# Check if IEnumerable is of a ValueType (at runtime)

Tags: c#, reflection, value-type

How do I check if an object I receive as a **method result** is not `ValueType` and not `IEnumerable<ValueType>`?

Here is what I wrote:

```
MethodInfo selectedOverload = SelectOverload(selectedMethodOverloads);
object result = ExecuteAndShowResult(selectedOverload);
ExploreResult(result);

private static void ExploreResult(object result)
{
 if (result != null &&
     !(result is ValueType) &&
     !((IEnumerable)result).GetType().GetProperty("Item").PropertyType) is ValueType)
    )
    Console.WriteLine("explore");
}
```

Unfortunately type of `PropertyType` is `Type`, its content is the type I need to check (e.g. `int`) but I don't know how to.

**EDIT:**

Ok, the `.IsValueType` worked, but now I want also to exclude strings (which are not recognized as ValueTypes), so what?

```
!(((IEnumerable)result).GetType().GetProperty("Item").PropertyType is string)
```

doesn't work!

**EDIT 2:**

Just answered myself:

```
!(((IEnumerable)result).GetType().GetProperty("Item").PropertyType == typeof(string))
```

---

**The question remains open** about what if I want to check the inheritance from a base class:

```
!(((IEnumerable)result).GetType().GetProperty("Item").PropertyType == typeof(BaseClass))
```

doesn't work because **typeof** checks runtime type, and if `PropertyType == InheritedClassType` it will return false...

Comment: Do you simply mean `GetProperty("Item").PropertyType.IsValueType` ?

Comment: Thanks for responses! That's exaclty what I need.

Comment: But just abstract from OP. What if I need to check if the IEnumerable is of some type (even base classes)?

Comment: Since the parameter is of type `object` any value types will be boxed, so you *know* that it's not a value type.  You are 100% certain that it is always a reference type.  If the method is generic, then it could be either.

Comment: @Servy If my object is actually a `List<int>`, values are not likely to be boxed.

Comment: "If a value type is used for type T, the compiler generates an implementation of the List<T> class specifically for that value type. That means a list element of a List<T> object does not have to be boxed before the element can be used, and after about 500 list elements are created the memory saved not boxing list elements is greater than the memory used to generate the class implementation."

Comment: @Teejay Yes, it's possible for the object to be a reference type implementing `IEnumerable` with a value type as the generic argument, that is true.  But the object itself will *never* be a value type, because if it were, it would be boxed, making it a reference.  If you want to know if it's a boxed value type, that's fine, I'm just making sure you're aware that technically, `result` is *never* a value type.  While it's not 100% clear what you want, it really does seem that the method should be generic, using generic constraints.

Comment: @Servy I understand you, but what you say seems not to be true.
If I call `ExploreResult(5)` then `(result is ValueType)` evaluates to true. Try it yourself!

Comment: Isn't this answers your question. `type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericArguments()[0].IsValueType`?

Comment: @Teejay Yes, it does, *and it's wrong*.  That's my point.  `result` isn't a value type, it's a *boxed value type*, which is a reference type.

Comment: @Servy Remember that .Net framework, like Java, does most of the boxings/unboxings. Otherwise you're stating that all .Net frameworks are WRONG.

Comment: @Teejay Yes.  What's your point?  `result` is still never going to be a value type, because it would need to be boxed if it were.  If you want to know if it's a boxed value type that's fine, just ensure you're aware of the distinction between a boxed value type and an *actual* value type.

Comment: @Servy Yes, I'm aware of that, but that's not what I need.

Comment: @Teejay I'm not saying that the framework is wrong, I'm saying that you're interpretation of that code is wrong.  Yes, `result is ValueType` returns true, because `result` can be implicitly converted to a `ValueType`.  `result` still isn't actually a value type, because it's boxed.  The definition of the `is` operator is such that it is working correctly.

Comment: @Servy I just need to know if I can "explore" more the result. If it's an **int**, (valuetype or boxed valuetype, doesn't matter), I can't.
If it's a reftype, I can explore its props and methods.

Comment: @Teejay Ah, then if that's your issue then the answer is that whether something is a value type is not a measure of whether or not it can be "broken down".  A user defined struct can have fields/properties/methods that may want to be broken down further, while a user defined class could just as easily have none of that.

Comment: @Servy Sure, but I have no struct, for the moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Type.IsValueType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isvaluetype.aspx):

```
private static void ExploreResult(object result)
{
 if (result != null &&
     !(result.GetType().IsValueType) &&
     !((IEnumerable)result).GetType().GetProperty("Item").PropertyType.IsValueType)
    )
    Console.WriteLine("explore");
}
```

Although if `result` is not a value type but not an `IEnumerable` than you'll get a cast error.  That check needs some work.

**Answer to second part**

```
!((IEnumerable)result).GetType().GetProperty("Item").PropertyType is string)
```

is always false because `PropertyType` returns a `Type` which is never a string.  I think you want

```
!(result.GetType().GetProperty("Item").PropertyType == typeof(string))
```

Note that I took out the cast to `IEnumerable` since you're looking for a property through reflection anyways, so the cast is irrelevant.

**Answer to third edit**

> I want to check the inheritance from a baseclass

For that you want `type.IsAssignableFrom()`:

```
Type itemType = result.GetType().GetProperty("Item").PropertyType;
bool isInheritedFromBaseClass = 
    typeof(BaseClass).IsAssignableFrom(itemType);
```

Comment: Oh yes, sorry, in the code I wrote here I forgotten the `if (result is IEnumerable)` part :)

Comment: Needs more work than that - `IEnumerable.Item` is defined as `object`.  If you want to know if it's an `IEnumerable<T>` and that `T` is a value type, you'll need to do some reflection against the generic type parameter.

Comment: No, "Item" just return the type of the enumerator, just tried.

Comment: @Teejay I was wrong - `IEnumerable` doesn't have an `Item` property at all.  You're getting lucky that the underlying type is both an `IEnumerable` and an `IEnumerable<T>`, which has a strongly-typed `Item` property. If the type was just a plain `IEnumerable` (like an `ArrayList`)  you'd get a runtime exception.